# Yii2: Form Validation Either one is compulsory

Tags: validation, yii2

I have two different models for example.

Model 1: User
Model 2: company

I have a single form where we take user profile information along with company information.

We have an email from user model and work email from company model and I want either one compulsory to submit the form.

I know others also ask the questions on either one compulsory but they ask on the same model but I have two models in a single form

Comment: how are you using the 2 different models , if i would have to do such kind of work i would create a separate model that extends the `yii\base\Model` and define all the respective fields from 2 or more models if necessary and then validate all of them as a single model the similar way as all other solutions are working

Comment: Creating custom validation is less complicated.

Comment: as Muhammad Omer Aslam mentioned, you should have a new model (ex. UserCompanyFormModel) for your form that contains all your fields. Post validation, you can generate a new User and Company from this new model.

Comment: thanks, guys for your valuable comment can you share the link where I can study this as I am new to yii2

Comment: see here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-models